# Keep the same ID on an item copied from another list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, caml-query, csom, item

Environment : Foundation 2010

I have two helpdesk lists. In List A, the user create the item and an ID is automatically assigned.

My workflow is used to **copy** that item in the list B. However **IDs are not the same** (because in some cases some elements are archived). Then I want to keep the same ID on both items.

I see that we can do it with Powershell, but I don't have any access to the Central Administration. Maybe with Client Object Model ? I never use that before.

I tried with lookup field but it doesn't work, as well.

Another way to do that ? It's terrible to see that Sharepoint doesn't even include that functionnality...

**EDIT :** Here's a screen of which "ID" I'm talking about (ID directly in the list)

[image]

**EDIT 2 :** Here's a screenshot of the update action

[image]

Comment: are you  speaking of sharepoint internal ID? like item.ID?

Comment: @Gwny Updated my post. I'm talking about the ID directly in the list. I want to keep the same IDs to work with in my workflow.

Comment: you cannot have same ID diectly, workaround is possible untill the same item ID is present in 2nd list

Comment: you can create extra column with name 'OrigID' in list 2, and store the list 1 item ID in OrigID column in list 2, and use that column as reference in workflow. like primary and foreign key concept

Comment: I cannot do that. I dont have the option "ID" when I try to update. I can just update the "Content Type ID" which can only have thses values : "Problem" or "Folder".

Comment: No, ID value is maintained by SharePoint and you can **not** change it... Well.. that is not completely true.. it is a value in the SQL server database, so it can be changed... deep down in a database table.. BUT.. when you do you loose all support from Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each list keeps its own IDs and you will not be able to keep them perfectly in sync. Create a helper columns and let the workflow copy the ListA ID into that field, then refer to that field as the common ID.

If you use the workflow step "Create item" instead of copying an item, you can transfer any field value from the current item to the new item, as shown in the screenshot, where the Title field in the other list will get the ID of the current item.

[image]

**Edit I**: I think you need to forget about the SharePoint ID and create a unique ID with a workflow. Write that unique ID to a field in List B and then also write that same ID into a field in List A. That way you can identify an item in the other list by the unique ID.

**Edit II**: Create a helper list (IDNumber) with one item and a number field. This will have the last used unique ID number. Manually set to any number you want as your start number. The ID of this item is easy to find out. Should be 1, if not, look it up.

User creates item in ListA, workflow kicks off, set a variable to the value of IDNumber item where ID = 1 (i.e. look up the last used IDNumber). Use a Calculate step to add 1 to that variable and write to variable NextNumber.

Then write NextNumber to item in ListA, create item in ListB, write NextNumber to item in ListB. Finally set only item in list IDNumber to NextNumber.

Comment: I cannot do that. I dont have the option "ID" when I try to update. I can just update the "Content Type ID" which can only have thses values : "Problem" or "Folder".

Comment: Of course you can copy the ID. I added a screenshot.

Comment: Thank you. However, I need to "Search a list item" with a field and a value corresponding. I added a picture in my first post. So, I cannot find elements by ID because they're not yet updated, see ?

Comment: I don't understand. If you use a workflow on an item, it must have been saved already, so it must have an ID. User creates item in List A. Workflow starts and creates item in List B. Write ListA ID field to another column in List B.

Comment: Or are you trying to change an EXISTING list item in another list?

Comment: He needs to link the current item to the updated item to change the ID. But with which field link them? He wants just the ID to be the same, so he can't link the two lists items before update the ID

Comment: My list A has a workflow : it copies the item in list B AND it updates the item in list B, directly. My list B has a workflow which made some other things. You see ? In my picture, I'm trying to update my "TrueID" field while searching if the value of "TrueID" equals to the value of my current item. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I added a suggestion in my answer.

Comment: Ok but, what about incrementing ? How can I automatically put values which will never be the same ?

Comment: I added a suggestion about incrementing.